# How to create new stack using create-change-set in AWS Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, changeset

I'm able to use change-sets on an existing AWS stack. I read this [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-console-create-stacks-changesets.html) and it seems it's also possible to create a change set for a new stack.

Now I try to do it using the CLI:

```
aws cloudformation create-change-set --change-set-name ChangeSet-82 --stack-name test-bucket-xx --region eu-west-1 --template-body file://xxx
```

This returns an error:

```
An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateChangeSet operation: Stack [test-bucket-xx] does not exist.
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The type of change set operation. To create a change set for a new stack, specify CREATE. To create a change set for an existing stack, specify UPDATE .

```
--change-set-type CREATE
```

[Source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/create-change-set.html)

> To create a change set for a stack that doesn't exist, for the
>   change-set-type parameter, specify CREATE . To create a change set for
>   an existing stack, specify UPDATE for the change-set-type parameter.
>   After the create-change-set call successfully completes, AWS
>   CloudFormation starts creating the change set. To check the status of
>   the change set or to review it, use the describe-change-set action.

Comment: what if you don't know if it is created yet?

Comment: I ended putting a try catch in my pipeline but would be kinda nice to have it part of the CLI

Comment: You can check out if a stack hasn't been created yet by using awscli:
`aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name myStack`